# Función mouseenter de jquery se llama multiples veces incluso si ya estoy moviendome dentro del div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

No sé que pueda estar pasando, antes tenía `mouseover` en lugar de `mouseenter` y me pasaba exactamente lo mismo, según había leído que con `mouseenter` solo se llamaba a la función cuando el puntero entraba al elemento, pero parece ser que en mi caso no es así.

Hay 4 `divs` que funcionan como bloques de servicios, cada uno va a tener un fondo específico, y hay otro `div` escondido que primero tiene un `display none`, pero aparece en grande cubriendo todo el tamaño que abarcaban estos 4 bloques de servicios con el fondo ahora extendido del `div` del cual se está pasando encima el puntero.

Código JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#serv-arq")
    .mouseenter(function() {
        console.log('Estoy en la capa de arq');
        $("#capa").css('background-color','darkblue');
        $(".services").css('background-color','transparent');
        $("#capa").css('display','block');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        console.log('Salí de capa de arq');
        $("#capa").css('background-color','transparent');
        $("#capa").css('display','none');
        $(".service-1").css('background-color','darkblue');
        $(".service-2").css('background-color','red');
        $(".service-3").css('background-color','yellow');
        $(".service-4").css('background-color','green');
    });

    $("#serv-ing")
    .mouseenter(function() {
        console.log('Estoy en la capa de ing');
        $("#capa").css('background-color','red');
        $(".services").css('background-color','transparent');
        $("#capa").css('display','block');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        console.log('Sali capa ing');
        $("#capa").css('background-color','transparent');
        $("#capa").css('display','none');
        $(".service-1").css('background-color','darkblue');
        $(".service-2").css('background-color','red');
        $(".service-3").css('background-color','yellow');
        $(".service-4").css('background-color','green');
    });

    $("#serv-bim")
    .mouseenter(function() {
        console.log('Estoy en la capa de bim');
        $("#capa").css('background-color','yellow');
        $(".services").css('background-color','transparent');
        $("#capa").css('display','block');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        console.log('Sali capa bim');
        $("#capa").css('background-color','transparent');
        $("#capa").css('display','none');
        $(".service-1").css('background-color','darkblue');
        $(".service-2").css('background-color','red');
        $(".service-3").css('background-color','yellow');
        $(".service-4").css('background-color','green');
    });

    $("#serv-con")
    .mouseenter(function() {
        console.log('Estoy en la capa de con');
        $("#capa").css('background-color','darkblue');
        $(".services").css('background-color','transparent');
        $("#capa").css('display','block');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        console.log('Sali capa con');
        $("#capa").css('background-color','transparent');
        $("#capa").css('display','none');
        $(".service-1").css('background-color','darkblue');
        $(".service-2").css('background-color','red');
        $(".service-3").css('background-color','yellow');
        $(".service-4").css('background-color','green');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent-capa" id="parent-capa">
        <div class="capa" id="capa"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex col-3 services service-1" id="serv-arq">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
            <h3 class="text-center w-100">Arquitectura</h3>
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-uppercase">Ver más</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex col-3 services service-2" id="serv-ing">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
            <h3 class="text-center w-100">Ingeniería</h3>
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-uppercase">Ver más</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex col-3 services service-3" id="serv-bim">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
            <h3 class="text-center w-100">BIM</h3>
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-uppercase">Ver más</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex col-3 services service-4" id="serv-con">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
            <h3 class="text-center w-100">Construcción</h3>
            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-uppercase">Ver más</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#parent-capa{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.capa{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

.services{
    height: 600px;
}
.service-1{
    background-color: darkblue;
}
.service-2{
    background-color: red;
}
.service-3{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.service-4{
    background-color: green;
}
```

El estado actual lo pueden ver en: https://demos.posicionart.com/grupocob/

Comment: Realmente que es lo que quieres hacer? eso te pasa por que en el mouseenter estas colocando un div sobre el div que ejecuta el evento por lo cual se ejecuta el mouseleave, se desaparece el div que colocas sobre el otro y se vuelve a ejecutar el mouseenter y así sucesivamente, me hago entender?

Comment: Quizás podrías asociarle el `mouseenter`a las columnas de los servicios pero el `mouseleave` asociarlo a la capa nueva que se superpone delante de los servicios. De esta manera al colocar el puntero encima de las columnas de servicios se mostraría la capa que se superpone sin producirse automaticamente el `mouseleave` y sin entrar en ese bucle epiléptico tan molesto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente lo que se me ocurrió fue cambiar tu lógica y ejecutar el `mouseleave` en el `div#capa` que aparece al hacer `mouseenter` en los `div.servicios`.

También reduje tu código para que no quedara taaan largo, saludos.

**EDICIÓN**

En un comentario el OP solicita que sin salir del `div#capa` que se superpone y al movilizarse de manera horizontal sobre esta se cambie su `background` por el del `div.servicios` en el cual debería estar posicionado el cursor.

**Explicación:** Para lograr esto simplemente añadí un evento `mousemove` al elemento `#capa`, luego utilizando un `each` recorro todos los `div` que tienen la clase `servicios` y comparo que la posición `X` del cursor en relación al `div#capa` sea mayor a la posición `left` del `div` actual, si esto se cumple se sobreentiende que ya me encuentro dentro de dicho `div` por lo cual asigno su color de `background` a `#capa`.

Expliqué lo mejor que puse espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".services")
    .mouseenter(function() {
      var background = $(this).css('background-color');
        $("#capa").css({
          'background-color': background,
          'display': 'block'
        });
    });
    
    $("#capa").mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).css({
          'display': 'none'
        });
    })
    
    $("#capa").mousemove(function(e){      
      $(".services").each(function(index, elemento){
        if(e.originalEvent.clientX >= $(elemento).offset().left){
          $("#capa").css({
            'background': $(elemento).css('background')
          })
        }
      })
    })
});
```

```css
#parent-capa{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.capa{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

.services{
    height: 600px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
.service-1{
    background-color: darkblue;
}
.service-2{
    background-color: red;
}
.service-3{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.service-4{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-capa" id="parent-capa">
    <div class="capa" id="capa"></div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex col-3 services service-1" id="serv-arq">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
        <h3 class="text-center w-100">Arquitectura</h3>
        <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-uppercase">Ver más</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex col-3 services service-2" id="serv-ing">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
        <h3 class="text-center w-100">Ingeniería</h3>
        <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-uppercase">Ver más</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex col-3 services service-3" id="serv-bim">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
        <h3 class="text-center w-100">BIM</h3>
        <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-uppercase">Ver más</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex col-3 services service-4" id="serv-con">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center">
        <h3 class="text-center w-100">Construcción</h3>
        <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-uppercase">Ver más</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, ¡Sí funciona! pero parcialmente :( Es que ahora solo cambia el color del fondo cuando sale de la capa, pero igual mi intención es que sin salir de la capa cambiara con el hecho de pasar a otro div, no sé igual si puedas ayudarme con eso, sino igual de tu respuesta y cambios puedo intentar yo el solucionarlo

Comment: Olvída mi comentario anterior, creo la manera de solucionar eso es que en lugar de que aparezca una nueva capa encima, cambie el fondo de cada una de las columnas.

Comment: @JuanArturoCruzCardona revisa la edición que acabo de hacer al código, se me ocurrió una forma de hacerlo, en minutos edito la explicación de la pregunta.

Comment: @JuanArturoCruzCardona listo, editado completamente espero haber sido claro, en caso de que no te resolveré las dudas que tengas.

Comment: ¡Está perfecto! Muchas gracias, es una solución mejor a lo que tenía pensando, mil gracias :D

Comment: @JuanArturoCruzCardona Me alegra te gustara la solución, saludos.